# string to b&w image

Tags: python, image

In Python the string:

```
a = '00001111\n00110011\n00110101\n.....'
```

How would I convert that to an image of let's say 8x8 pixels where 0 stands for black and 1 stands for white. Is the route to study for example BMP and make a BMP file from it. Or are there smoother roads to enlightenment?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Do you know about the [Python Image Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)?

Comment: I did have a quick look at PIL thought that it was only good for manipulating images... should I've a closer look is that what you're saying?

Comment: Yes, you can use PIL to create images from scratch as well.

Comment: Ok thanx, I'll have a shot at PIL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to convert your string to a sequence of bytes containing the proper values:

```
pixel_value = {'0': 0, '1': 255}
byte_seq = ''.join(chr(pixel_value[c]) for c in a if c in pixel_value)
```

Then use [PIL's `Image.fromstring`](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm) to convert it to an image:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.fromstring('L', (8, 8), byte_seq)
im.show()
```